# Java ME Default Emulator File Storage

Tags: java, java-me, emulation

I created an app in which a file is created. The file directory I chosen was `Pictures/` folder of `Library` (WINDOWS 7).

The emulator enlists the created file but it is not found in my hard disk in `pictures/` directory.

Where is the file actually created and how can I access this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in emulator help documentation ([also available online](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/z400000c31767.html)).

> ### FileConnection API
>
> On a real device, the FileConnection API typically provides access to files stored in the device’s memory or on a memory card.
>
> In the Java ME Platform SDK emulator, the FileConnection API enables MIDlets to access files stored on your computer’s hard disk.
>
> The files that can be accessed using FileConnection are stored in subdirectories of `USER_HOME/javame-sdk/3.0/work/emulator-instance/appdb/filesystem`. For example, the `DefaultCldcPhone1` emulator skin comes with a root directory installed called `root1`, which contains a Readme file and an empty directory named `photos`. The full path of the file is: `USER_HOME/javame-sdk/3.0/work/emulator-instance/appdb/filesystem\root1\photos`
>
> ...Each subdirectory of filesystem is called a **root**. The Java ME Platform SDK provides a mechanism for managing roots. While the emulator is running, choose View > External Events Generator from the emulator window’s menu. A utility window opens. Click the File Connection tab.
>
> [image: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/figures/filesystem-roots.gif]
>
> In the File Connection panel you can mount, unmount, or delete filesystem roots...

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful. For my own future reference, and that of others working on MacOS, I found the filesystem root at `/Applications/Java_ME_SDK_3.0.app/Contents/Resources/runtimes/cldc-hi-javafx/appdb/filesystem/root1`.